# BigCommerce checkoutSDK getShippingOptions() returns empty array

Tags: bigcommerce

I always get an empty array back from `getShippingOptions()` after setting the shipping address with the following code:

```
address = {
                firstName: 'Fulfillment Test',
                lastName: 'Fulfillment Tester',
                address1: '12345 Testing Way',
                address2: 'address2',
                city: 'Some City',
                stateOrProvinceCode: 'CA',
                postalCode: '95555',
                countryCode: 'US',
                phone: '555-555-5555',
                customFields: [
                    {
                        fieldId: "field_25",
                        fieldValue: 0
                    }
                ]
            };
const state = await service.updateShippingAddress(address);
const newstate = await service.loadShippingOptions();
console.log(newstate.data.getShippingOptions());
```

I am using `@bigcommerce/checkout-sdk: ^1.32.1`

Comment: Hi! have you setup your shipping options correctly in the control panel?

Comment: Yes, I can get shipping options back from the server-server API.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get shipping options back after deleting all existing shipping zones and re-adding them in the BigCommerce store shipping settings.